# New pipeline on Azure DevOps shows error message "Some recent issues detected related to pipeline trigger."

Tags: azure-pipelines

I created a brand new CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps using a yaml file that is working in another pipeline, no problem. I set its default branch to cloud-main, not master as is the suggestion. The new pipeline gives me the message "Some recent issues detected related to pipeline trigger." Running the pipeline works fine. How do I get rid of the error message?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To fix this and remove the error I went to

- Edit the pipeline >
- ... (menu shown by three dots in upper right corner) >
- Triggers >
- YAML (tab across the top of the page) >
- click list item 'Get sources' >
- On the right panel there's a dropdown menu
  full of git branches under the label 'Default branch for manual and
  scheduled builds' that was on 'master', I changed it to cloud-main.
  cloud-main is the branch I want to be default. That's also the branch
  I chose earlier when making the pipeline.

Strange that I have to drill down into this setting to change it. Hope my experience helps someone else who is getting this same error.

Comment: Our build had the error on master, our default branch. We fixed it by swapping the default branch to dev, then back to master

Comment: I was getting this and didn't want to change my default branch, but I just changed the branch and set it back and saved and the error went away. When I went to the pipeline history and checked the diff, I saw the default branch changed from `uat` to `refs/heads/uat`. Not sure how that changed or why, but it is what it is.

Comment: Same as @ldam I was getting the error unexpectedly. Change my branch under the "get sources" UI, saved; then changed my branch back to the original and saved again. Error is gone now. Not sure where the hang up was, glad it was an easy fix tho.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Some-recent-issues-detected-related-to-p/1620293

this was a bug in a previous version of devops.

I was able to solve it on our devops version (which does not yet run the version with the fix) by simply updating the yaml file with a comment. I had this idea from this post:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Some-recent-issues-detected-related-to-p/1620293#T-N1630570